# Eigenvalues of Symmetric Pseudo-Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm interested in calculating the eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix where the left and right diagonals are 1 and the main diagonal has entries $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I was wondering if there was a reference where the eigenvalues are derived.

\begin{equation*}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & a_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a_3 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & a_4 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & a_{n-1} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & a_n
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

The special case that I am particularly interested in, is when $a_2 = a_3 = \cdots = a_{n-1} = 0$ and $a_1,a_n \neq 0$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant and noticed that due to this, you can write down the characteristic polynomial quickly.